# Handle dependencies between git feature branches

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I am part of a software developer team, where we are using a simple git branching strategy consisting of one long living main branch and arbitrarily many short living feature branches. To keep the history of the main branch as linear as possible, we finish feature branches by squashing them into single commits on top of the main branch and deleting them afterwards. This works nicely as long as we do not have dependencies between different feature branches.

In some rare situations however, we cannot avoid ending up like this

```
    o---o---o---o---o  main
         \   \       \
          \   o---o---o  feature1
           \       \   \
            o---o---o---o  feature2
```

where some branch `feature2` depends on another branch `feature1`. Ideally, we would like to finish `feature1` without losing connection to `feature2`. That is, we would like to squash-commit `feature1` on top of `main` but also rewrite the history of `feature2` to still being dependent of that squashed commit. After finishing `feature1` the history should look like that:

```
    o---o---o--o--o--o'  main
         \            \
          o---o---o'---o'  feature2
```

Is this achievable without having to deal with (avoidable) merge conflicts?

---

**Added later:** I just realized that something very similar is possible in the following way:

- squash-commit `feature1` onto `main`
- merge `main` into `feature1`
- merge `feature1` into `feature2`
- delete `feature1`

This has the advantage of not rewriting the history of `feature2` while still keeping the history of `main` linear.

Do you think this could be the ideal solution?

Comment: The solution you added later looks good to me. Those merges will prevent spurious conflicts later.

Comment: The _ideal_ solution would be not to squash-merge. A squash merge, despite the name, is _not a merge_. Therefore the history is lost by definition; each commit simply magically appears at the end of main, as if everyone were working in turns directly on main. This makes it much more difficult (than it would normally be) to write feature branches that depend on other feature branches. If you insist on continuing to do things this way, you must _expect_ to get unnecessary merge conflicts.

Comment: Another downside of your architecture is that a PR (are you using PRs?) displays commits that really have nothing to do with that branch. Thus the reviewer ends up having to review the same "changes" _again_.

Comment: @matt Technically, we don't use PRs, but we still review feature branches before finishing, so your concerns apply indeed. I hope my suggestion (see "added later") solves that issue since `feature2` is depending on `main` after finishing `feature1` in the proposed way. A diff between `feature2` and `main` will hopefully not contain changes coming from `feature1`.

Comment: Agreed; a diff is an artificial ephemeral construct, so if that's all you're looking at during the review, you'll see what you need to see and no more. A formal PR, on the other hand, is made up of _commits_. Git hosts (such as GitHub) have a coherent way of dealing with PR branches that depend on other PR branches, both before and after the latter are merged into main. Your procedure loses that advantage.

Comment: Also I should mention that the usual thing, if feature B depends on feature A, is simply to grow feature B right off the end of feature A — and then, if A gets additional commits before merging, to rebase B onto the new end of A. So your entire approach is very unusual and you're sort of making your own problems.

Comment: @matt I see.. Is it unusual in your opinion to clean up (to linearize) the main branches history in the first place? Or is there just a better way to achieve the same goal?

Comment: Mmmmm, I've been in situations where they did that. But I much prefer situations where we do real merges and let the history speak for itself. That's what history is for. I can understand squashing a PR branch's commits _before_ submitting it, and indeed I do a _lot_ of cleanup of my commits before submitting the PR; but even so I make _real_ merges with _real_ merge commits and thus a preserved historical topology.

Comment: What I think would be the ideal solution is: `rebase main feature1` followed by running [git test](https://github.com/mhagger/git-test) on all commits. `git checkout main; git merge --no-ff feature1; git branch -d feature1`. Then `git rebase main feature2` (followed by `git test`), and finally `git checkout main; git merge --no-ff feature2; git branch -d feature2` . That gives a history that is superior to any alternative.